# Transparent background showing up as black on api 14-15

Tags: android

I have a progress bar which I set its background to be transparent. It works for newer versions of android but on 14 and 15 it shows up as black. Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".RaceActivity" >
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/speedometer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/speedometer_title" 
    android:layout_below="@id/current_distance_title" 
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/speedometer_progress_bar" 
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

The theme of my application is android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar.

Any ideas how to make it transparent?

Comment: It might be that the application theme is black, so although you have a transparency on the progress bar, the container element has a black background.

Comment: Thanks for your help stevebot I replied to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the theme that you are using. Make sure that you explicitly set the color of the view underneath the progress bar.

Holo Light and Holo Dark set different default backgrounds for root elements, so overriding them may solve your problem.

http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html

Comment: I marked this answer as right even though I'm not sure it is the answer but it is likely. I ended up editing @drawable/speedometer_progress_bar which is a layer list and the bottom item is @android:id/background . For some reason it is transparent in api 17 or higher of android but black in 16 or lower might be related to the theme. I added a <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> to that item and that did the trick. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#00FFFFFF` color instead of `@android:color/transparent`.
It work for me.